# Designating Other than First Row as Headers in R

Tags: r

I have data in a .csv that I am trying to pull into R. Using the following command:

```
data=read.table("C:\\Users\\Riemman\\Desktop\\IWM_Minute_Data.csv",header=TRUE,sep=",",skip=2)
```

the data in the CSV file is structured so that the first row in the row in the data file is empty, the second row are the headers and the data starts at the third row. How do I tell R to designate the second row and not the first as the header row??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can read it in without headers then add them later

```
data <- read.csv("C:\\Users\\Riemman\\Desktop\\IWM_Minute_Data.csv",header=F)
colnames(data) <- data[2,]
data <- data[c(-1,-2),]
```

Answer (score 6):

Just use the `skip=` parameter to skip lines at the beginning of the file. That will allow you to keep header=T and have the right col names

```
data <- read.csv("IWM_Minute_Data.csv",skip=1)
```

Comment: Nice, `?read.csv` suggests this only works if header is the first line of the file, but in fact it works as you say.

Comment: @user3114046 `read.csv` is just a wrapper to `read.table` with a few different default values set. I prefer using `read.table` all the time myself to get the most flexibility.

Comment: Yes, and all the different `read.table` versions sit in the same help file. The help entry for `header` says "a logical value indicating whether the file contains the names of the variables as its first line." But per your answer, this is not correct; the first *non-empty* line is used as the header, *regardless* of whether you use `skip` to skip those lines. Your code above works without `skip = 1`.

Comment: @user3114046 Ah. ok. So i guess it does skip blank lines automatically. But if there was data in that first row, like some report header, you should skip it with `skip=`. But then after you `skip` it won't not skip other blank lines apparently. So header is the first line non-blank line, or the first line after the skip is applied (at least in my tests).

Comment: I agree, that's consistent with my testing.

Answer (score 2):

Why not remove the first row?

```
filename <- "C:\\Users\\Riemman\\Desktop\\IWM_Minute_Data.csv"
tmp <- readLines(filename)[-1]
writeLines(tmp, filename)
data <- read.table(tmp, header = TRUE, sep = "")
```

Comment: Thanks fr your help. What if I am getting a "Permission Denied" response as it is trying, yet filing, to open a connection?